# Why php-fpm from official Docker image doesn't work for me?

Tags: php, curl, docker

I try to run a new container from `php:fpm`:

`docker run --name fpmtest -d -p 80:9000 php:fpm`

By default, it exposes port 9000 in its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/32887c1de338d0ad582393b5f1dafd292334423f/5.6/fpm/Dockerfile).

Then I log in into container and create index.html file:

```
$ docker exec -i -t fpmtest bash
root@2fb39dd6a40b:/var/www/html# echo "Hello, World!" > index.html
```

And inside the container I try to get this content with `curl`:

```
# curl localhost:9000
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Outside the container I get another error:

```
$ curl localhost
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: I don't think php-fpm is a http server, you should get a working http server with php-fpm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the purpose of that container. There is not a web server listening.

The port 9000 of the container is a socket that a web server can use to communicate with the php interpreter.

In [the parent folder](https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/32887c1de338d0ad582393b5f1dafd292334423f/5.6) of the git repository you linked, there is another folder which runs an apache container, it seems to be there to work together with the fpm container.

I guess in your case you should do:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-apache-php-app -v /PATH/TO/WEB-FILES:/var/www/html php:5.6-apache
```

Here is the official documentation to work with php docker images:

https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/php/

---

**As an example**, let's say we want to use that php-fpm container **with another container running the nginx web server**.

First, create a directory with the php files, for example:

```
mkdir content
echo '<?php echo "Hello World!"?>' > content/index.php
```

Then, create another directory `conf.d`, and inside it create a `default.conf` file with this content:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass fpmtestdocker:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Note the fastcgi_pass param value. Well, with this scenario, we run first:

```
docker run --name fpmtest -d -p 9000:9000 -v $PWD/content:/var/www/html php:fpm
```

And then:

```
docker run --name nginxtest -p 80:80 --link fpmtest:fpmtestdocker -v $PWD/content:/var/www/html -v $PWD/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d -d nginx
```

And that's it. We can go to http://localhost and see the results.

To take into account:

- Both containers needs access to the same /var/www/html directory. They shares paths to the app files.
- `--link fpmtest:fpmtestdocker` param so that the fpm container is visible from the nginx container. Then we can add the `fastcgi_pass fpmtestdocker:9000;` config directive in the nginx server config.

Comment: Juanra, it's interesting.. thanks. BTW, in front of php-fpm I use nginx, maybe it's a problem in nginx config..

Comment: In that case, you have to change your virtual-host config file and replace what normally is "fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;" with "fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;". Assuming you are using the same port exposed by the container by default...

Comment: can you update your question post include dockerfile for your nginx image, nginx.conf and the docker run command you use to launch nginx?

Comment: Hey booyaa, I've updated my post with a working example. I've not used dockerfiles for simplicity, but I think it's easy to adapt to that: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/nginx/ . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but loosely based on md5's excellent [gist](https://gist.github.com/md5/d9206eacb5a0ff5d6be0). To use this image with nginx, your Dockerfile for that image look like this:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.7
COPY php-fpm.conf /etc/nginx.conf.d/default.conf
```

An example of the nginx.conf that you copy over might look like this.

**php-fpm.conf**

```
server { 
  listen 80; 
  server_name localhost; 
  root /var/www/html; 

  index index.php; 

  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { 
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
      return 404;
    }

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

    fastcgi_pass   fpmtest:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php; 
  } 
}
```

Note *fastcgi_pass* references your container name (fpmtest).

Comment: booyaa, thanks, it's very interesting link! BTW, this way there will be at least two containers.. Is it a good idea to create an image with php-fpm + nginx to have them then in one container?

Comment: no that's an anti-pattern. each container should have a specific role. if this feels like extra overhead, you should use something like [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#compose-documentation) to build the infrastructure in the correct order i.e. build data volumes, fire up db, php-fpm and then webserver.